# Best metric for evaluation of mixture-of-Gaussian clusters on big-data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, large-data

I have made a new algorithm that is specifically crafted for clustering very large datasets.  In order to document it as a research paper, I have to choose one or two **internal (no-label) cluster evaluation measures** to evaluate my algorithm. Which algorithm do you think is generally the best choice for **big datasets**? And **why?**

**EDIT:**

My algorithm is a modified version of Expectation-Maximization Gaussian mixture models. In other words, the whole data is described by

$$P_(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{K}\pi(c_k)\mathcal{N}(\mu_k,\Sigma_k)$$

where $\pi(c_1),\ldots,\pi(c_K)$ are mixture weights. The main difference between my algorithm and regular EM is that it uses some sampling and approximation tricks that accelerate EM. The objective function is the same (the log-likelihood which is to be maximized).

Should I use log-likelihood as the evaluation metric? or use other (which?) internal measures for such task? Is it rational?

Comment: Large data is many objects to cluster or many features (dimensionality)?

Comment: @ttnphns In my settings, I mean many instances, but average dimensionality. E.g. **100M** instances, 100 clusters, 200 feautres, that is **~100GB** of data!

Comment: You see, any clustering algorithm is "inclined" to produce clusters of a specific shape or clusters having a specific type of density. So, one of the "validation metrics" should be theoretically close to your algorithm. Still, some other metrics should be different, - for you to show that your algo is robust enough to data and can cope with clusters other algos can cope with.

Comment: So, nobody can recommend you any concrete until you describe your algorithm (with example). This site may be a good place to do it!

Comment: @ttnphns Yep, exactly! For example, k-means is inclined to make spherical clusters, therefore it is usually evaluated using sum-of-squared error (SSE) which also assumes the clusters to be spherical (i.e. clusters having the same variance and no correlation between features).
 
My question is actually whether there exits an evaluation measure for ellipsoidal clusters? (having different variances for each dimension, or even having a full co-variance matrix?)

Comment: OK, if "ellipsoidal" is the key point, maybe you make it clear in your question. Smth like "I want smth like SSE-based criterion, but for ellipsoidal, not sperical, clusters".

Comment: Exactly! that is the key point!

Comment: I would like to see the Log-likelihood on the data for your large gaussian mixture vs. an AIC optimal nonparametric density for the space.  Gaussian mixtures are good where the point-clouds in the space are reasonably approximated by hyper-ellipsoids.  If you have the wrong shapes in your clouds, then you need a more appropriate basis.

Comment: It looks like your algorithm is about speeding up K-means. In that case, just use whatever metric is relevant for that. Your aim would be to show that your algorithm does just as well, or only marginally worse than regular K-means, while being significantly faster for large datasets.

Comment: @HongOoi: My optimal performance would be that of a regular EM for estimating a Gaussian mixture model. While SSE is the proper choice for comparing to k-means, I am looking for some similar metric that is proper for GMM (that considers non-ellipsoidal shapes).

Comment: @EngrStudent : Since EM@GMM is my optimum solution, considering other shapes seems non-relevant because in this case, both EM and my-EM are prone to error

Comment: @Ali: If you know your data then you do know your data.  I'm a big fan of "trust but verify" (Walt Flom) and that makes me want to find a way for the data to demonstrate that EM@GMM is the appropriate solution.  If someone put planar or parallelepiped box patches in your space, they would be fit, but a top-hat (or parallelepiped-oid) mixture model might be more appropriate for them.  This is the difference between theory and practice: in theory they are the same, in practice they are different.

Answer (score 3):

No measure will work well for big data.

Every measure is an aggregation, say an *average*.

By adding more data, this aggregation **will only change at the very last digit(s)**.

In most cases, a *sample* will already yield a result of the same quality; by the law of large numbers.

But on the other hand, you'll quickly run into the situation where your numerical precision is an issue. Unless you have a very good implementation, chances are that numerical issues with your "big data" implementation will actually make the result *worse* than one on a sample, where these effects did not yet occur.

For EM type of algorithms, starting values will likely have much more influence than different algorithms. Same for k-means: adding more data doesn't really improve results. Because the algorithm only computes a rough aggregation of your data; and aggregating more data doesn't change the outcome a lot anymore.